# Compute Mean Target column of a feature with Spark in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to enhance my logistic regression model and I'm having trouble to compute the **mean target** column (https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-try-mean-encoding-17057262cd0) of a feature with Spark Scala

Let's say I have this dataset:

```
+---+--------+---+------+
|id |job     |age|target|
+---+--------+---+------+
|1  |Doctor  |54 |1     |
|2  |Doctor  |35 |0     |
|3  |Doctor  |28 |1     |
|4  |Doctor  |75 |0     |
|5  |Teacher |29 |1     |
|6  |Teacher |37 |1     |
|7  |Engineer|60 |0     |
|8  |Engineer|38 |1     |
|9  |Waiter  |31 |1     |
|10 |Driver  |31 |0     |
+---+--------+---+------+
```

And I want to compute the mean target between **job** and **target** and get:

```
+---+--------+--------+------+
|id |job     |job_mean|target|
+---+--------+--------+------+
|1  |Doctor  |0.5     |1     |
|2  |Doctor  |0.5     |0     |
|3  |Doctor  |0.5     |1     |
|4  |Doctor  |0.5     |0     |
|5  |Teacher |1.0     |1     |
|6  |Teacher |1.0     |1     |
|7  |Engineer|0.5     |0     |
|8  |Engineer|0.5     |1     |
|9  |Waiter  |1.0     |1     |
|10 |Driver  |0.0     |0     |
+---+--------+--------+------+
```

I can't find a way to do this efficiently with `agg()` and `withColumn()`.

This what I have done so far, but I'm struggling to take advantage of this, I'm sure there is a better way to do it and make it work :

```scala
def targetAverage(colName: String, colValue: String): Double = {
    val targetCounts = df
      .groupBy(colName, "target")
      .count()
      .orderBy(col(colName).desc)
    val totalCounts = targetCounts
      .groupBy(colName)
      .agg(sum("count").as("count"))
      .orderBy(col(colName).desc)

    val targetCount = targetCounts.where(s"target == 1 AND $colName == $colValue").first().getAs[Long]("count")
    val totalCount = totalCounts.where(s"$colName == $colValue").first().getAs[Long]("count")
    
    targetCount.floatValue()/totalCount.floatValue()
  }
```

How can I use it to compute a new column using `withColumn()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html) function combined with Spark's [average](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#avg(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.avg

input.withColumn("job_mean", avg("target").over(Window.partitionBy("job")))
```

this code produces the following dataframe (reordered by id):

```
+---+--------+---+------+--------+
|id |job     |age|target|job_mean|
+---+--------+---+------+--------+
|1  |Doctor  |54 |1     |0.5     |
|2  |Doctor  |35 |0     |0.5     |
|3  |Doctor  |28 |1     |0.5     |
|4  |Doctor  |75 |0     |0.5     |
|5  |Teacher |29 |1     |1.0     |
|6  |Teacher |37 |1     |1.0     |
|7  |Engineer|60 |0     |0.5     |
|8  |Engineer|38 |1     |0.5     |
|9  |Waiter  |31 |1     |1.0     |
|10 |Driver  |31 |0     |0.0     |
+---+--------+---+------+--------+
```